# Separator between navigation bar and view - iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios7

In iOS 7 there's a grey separator between the navigation bar and the view.

Back in iOS 6, there wasn't that horizontal line, thus the view would blend in with the navigation bar as if they were the same image. Now I don't know how to remove it...

I've tried resizing the view / navigation bar, but it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like an, um, interesting app. :)

Comment: Thank you :P But it's copyrighted ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

In your `viewDidLoad` method and let me know :)

If you need this effect on every ViewController, you could simply do:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]
```

Or you'll need to do this where you first instantiate the navigation controller. For example, if the navigation controller is the root view controller of your app you can simply do

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

in your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

If, on the other end, you instantiate it through a segue you could do (in the appropriate view controller)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"navController"]){     
       UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
       nav.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
   }
}
```

And so on (if you're actually instantiating it from code, it should be the easiest option).

Comment: This removed the dim effect from the navigation bar, but didn't remove the shadow :). Is there any way to add this to AppDelegate to have effect over every navigation bar? (Didn't work: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:YES];)

Answer (score 28):

The other answers did not work for me. To remove the separator, I had to set the background image AND the shadow image, like so:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: You should add this line as well: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]; Otherwise navigation bar will be completely transparent

Answer (score 20):

Add this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

in your AppDelegate.m in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: That removed the shadow, but the other answer removed the dimmer look, wish I could accept both answers :)