# Hide separtor line between navigationBar and Content

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to delete this junction (The line between the navigation bar and the ImageView Orange):

[image: This line between the navigation bar and the ImageView Orange]

Is there someone who knows how to do?

Comment: I dont think so that you can remove this line, which is a separation between view and navigation controller. I would suggest that hide navigation and add navigation items in view itself, which look and feels like whole view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921082/separator-between-navigation-bar-and-view-ios-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I implemented the following code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.navigationController != nil {
        hideBorder(self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
    }
}

func hideBorder(view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if view.isKindOfClass(UIImageView.classForCoder()) && view.frame.size.height <= 1 {
        view.hidden = true
        return true
    }

    for sub in view.subviews {
        if hideBorder(sub as! UIView) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify `AppDelegate` file and add below code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Change status bar color to white
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

    // To remove separtor line between navigation controller and view
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines in your `viewWillAppear`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for parent in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
        for childView in parent.subviews {
            if(childView is UIImageView) {
                childView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
```