# UINavigationController with Expandable bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

is there an option to put a custom view in navigation bar? where the view can behave like contacts detail view, where on scrolling the header view gets squeezed or expanded. the back button looks handled natively, which is preferable. I could not see any option in UINavigationController API. am I missing something?

[image: Large Navigation Bar]
[image: Small Navigation Bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a custom view that blends in with the navigation bar (looks the same at the point they meet). No special nav bar api's needed. This question talks about how to remove the separator and make it look like the nav bar and underlying view blend together: [Separator between navigation bar and view - iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921082/separator-between-navigation-bar-and-view-ios-7?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: after asking the question here, I started to exactly do what you suggested and it works! :-)